# Generating Random Sentences from Language Models

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, sampling, natural-language

I have different N gram language models trained on a corpus. I want to show that increasing N really leads to an improvement in modeling the training set.

**I don't understand how to generate random sentences using them?**

Please explain mathematically using probability terms and if possible any directions to implement. I assume this **sampling from the learnt distribution/ model** problem must be well studied, but I am not finding any resources, just a huge number of demonstrations of randomly generated data.

I know that once I start generating words, I can stop until a stop token such as ? or . is generated.

Same problem I have while generating random sentences using character level rnns trained on the same corpus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, figure out a way to start, which means have a way to randomly generate $N-1$ words.

Then, at each step of the generation:

- Pick a word, uniformly at random.
- Form an N-gram out of the picked word and the last $N-1$ words.
- Look up the probability of that particular $N$-gram.
- Generate a uniform random number between 0 and 1. If that number is smaller than the probability of your $N$-gram, "accept" the new word. Otherwise, go back to the start.\

Some details left as an exercise ;)

Comment: any standard algorithms/variants of this, what about temperature sampling etc ?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for there...